# how can I efficiently load multiple files in the same path to hadoop?

Tags: shell, hdfs, hadoop2

for example:
I have more than 10 files in path /home/doc/data/ : 202012.txt, 202101.txt, 202102.txt.......

If I WANT TO load all files for `2021` I have to use :

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/doc/data/202101.txt /home/doc/data/202102.txt /home/doc/data/202103.txt... $HDFSLOCATION
```

Is there any efficient way to avoid the code redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcard:

```
 hadoop fs -copyFromLocal "/home/doc/data/2021*.txt" $HDFSLOCATION
```